# How to insert an instruction that stores the address of a variable in LLVM pass?

Tags: clang, llvm

If x is an integer variable i.e., int x; -> %x=alloca i32

I want to insert an instruction %add = &(%x) into my IR code through a pass.

Is this possible by GEP instruction or any other means? I mean, %add = gep(x).

My Initial IR,

```
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  store volatile i32 50, i32* %i, align 4
```

for a C code

```
i=50;
```

I want to write a pass from which I get a modified IR like below,

Modified IR,

```
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  store volatile i32 50, i32* %i, align 4
  %i_addr = (Get address of i)
```

Thanks and appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

`%i` is already the address of the variable `i` -- you can see its type is `i32*`, which is a pointer. To get the value of `i` (50 in your example) you would need a `load` instruction.